# AWS CloudFormation – How can I include a pseudo parameter in a !Sub constructed string?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I am trying to use `!Ref` to sub in one of the CloudFormation pseudo parameters, `AWS::StackName`. How can I use `!Ref` within a constructed string that uses `!Sub`?

Here's what I tried:

`var1`, `var2`, `var3` are all parameters referenced from the parameters section of the template.

```
Name: !Sub /${var1}/${var2}/${var3}/${!Ref AWS::StackId}/albTargetGroup
```

Here's the error I get:

```
Parameter name: can't be prefixed with "ssm"
(case-insensitive). If formed as a path, it 
can consist of sub-paths divided by slash symbol; 
each sub-path can be formed as a mix of letters, numbers and the following 3 symbols .-_
```

Comment: the error seems to be complaining that `var1` is set to `ssm` which is a reserved prefix

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use `${AWS::StackId}`.  See [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-sub.html).

Also, the whole argument under `!Sub` has to be a string:

```
Name: !Sub '/${var1}/${var2}/${var3}/${AWS::StackId}/albTargetGroup'
```